# Edit Row in DataTable before Update to Database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview, datatable

this is the situation:

I have a DataGridView linked to a TableAdapter. As some of the columns of the Table are hidden from the DataGridView, the content of the hidden columns must be added prior to committing the changes to the database (some of these are foreign keys).

What I'm trying to do is to intercept the added rows, add the data to the relevant columns, then proceed to commit the changes. Here is the code:

```
var createdRows = (ExampleDataset.ExampleTableDataTable)this.ExampleDataset.ExampleTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
try
{
    if(createdRows != null)
    {
        foreach(var row in createdRows)
        {
            row.ID_OTHER_TABLE = this.idOtherTable;
            row.REF_OTHER_TABLE = this.refOtherTable;
        }
    }
    this.exampleTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ExampleDataSet);
    this.ExampleDataSet.AcceptChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error updating database: " + ex.Message);
}
```

What I can see by inspecting the tables in another view and by debugging, is that the added rows are being captured, the fields being edited, the rows saved to the database, but the added information inside the `foreach()` is not being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself, but I can not say for sure if this works because there were changes in the project and the components no longer make part of it. That being said, I think this is the correct way to accomplish what I wanted to do, based of similar use cases with other components.

The error is in the object used as argument in the Update method of the TableAdapter, as one should be using the DataTable on which the changes are being made. That is, using

```
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ExampleDataSet)
```

it tries to write the changes based on the DataSet's rows current state, but changes has not been committed to it yet. The correct way should be:

```
this.exampleTableTableAdapter.Update(createdRows)
```

Now I understand that this is what brinky pointed out, but back in the moment I couldn't see it in the code less been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are updating the actual data table with the modified data table data - you are creating a temp table, and modifying the data in it, but then it isn't used to modify the actual data anywhere.

Comment: I though of this, but if I try to add the row back to the data table after editing, I get an error saying the row is already in the table. Please help, I know I'm confused and the solution will turn out to be like one line of code.